# Firebase Github oAuth redirect to the app is not working

Tags: java, firebase, flutter, github

These codes were added in order to redirect back to the original app however, after the authorization it just stays on the website without any redirect.

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data 
        android:host="oauth redirect url"
        android:scheme="appname" />
</intent-filter>
```

```
void onClickGitHubLoginButton() async {
  const String url = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize" +
      "?client_id=" + "1435bc0f9fcfa1003de3" +
      "&scope=public_repo%20read:user%20user:email";

  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(
      url,
      forceSafariVC: false,
      forceWebView: false,
    );
  } else {
    print("CANNOT LAUNCH THIS URL!");
  }
}
```